# Calculating percentage of counts of a table in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate the threshold limits counts of a table. For example the count of my tables is 100 as below -

```
spark.sql("""select count(*) from dev.my_table_metrics""").show(10,False)
+--------+                                                                      
|count(1)|
+--------+
|100     |
+--------+
```

I want to derive a result as below wherw lower_limit is -5% of the count and upper limit is +5% of the count -

```
+--------+------------+-----------+                                                                      
|count(1)|upper_limit |lower_limit|
+--------+------------+-----------+
|100     |105         |95         |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

I tried using the percentile(100,5) function but running into errors as below.
`"cannot resolve 'percentile(100, CAST(5 AS DOUBLE), 1L)' due to data type mismatch`

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use `count(*)-(count(*)*0.05) as lower_limit, count(*)+(count(*)*0.05) as upper_limit` to calculate the metrics?

Comment: @PrakaasHM, just multiple by 0.95 and 1.05

Comment: Ya. That's great and simpler. My little brain missed thinking that way.

Answer (score -2):

```
spark.sql("""select count(*), count(*)-(count(*)*(5/100)) as lower_limit , count(*)+(count(*)*(5/100)) as upper_limit  from dev.my_table_metrics""").show(10,False)
+---------+-----------+-----------+                                              
|count(1) |lower_limit|upper_limit|
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|100      |95         |105        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: LOL.You are answering your own question based on my comment. Nice. Glad it worked